# Walk tree of objects for change detection

Tags: entity-framework-core

**TL;DR**: Can EFCore do some kind of `DetectChanges(someEntity)` and automatically walk the object tree from that entity?

My domain model is created in Domain Driven Design style, where object references are only within an aggregate (e.g. `PurchaseOrder.Lines` is a collection of `PurchaseOrderLine`) and associations outside of the aggregate are by `Id` only (e.g. `PurchaseOrder.CustomerId` is a `Guid`, instead of a property to a `Customer` object).

I am retrieving many objects from the DB and altering them. At the end of the process I want to decide which objects to save and which ones not to. So, I want to only save modified objects that I specifically state have changed via `PurchaseOrderRepository.Update(purchaseOrder)`, but I also want to ensure all related objects are checked for changes too (so I'd like EFCore to see that 2 objects were removed from `purchaseOrder.Lines` so should be deleted, and 1 new one was added).

I don't want to automatically save everything that is retrieved + modified, only what I explicitly state should be. Is this something that is possible?

For example:
If I load a lot of objects, modify them, and then they fail my domain validation, I want to abandon saving changes to those objects and instead save a new `Event` of some kind in the DB saying a file import failed.

Comment: You are loading entities and change them, but don't want to save these changes in the database? Then why do you edit them?

Comment: Maybe add command and query pattern along side DDD so things stay in command "storage" until they are finalized, and then written to the DB, where they will be available on the query side.

Comment: It would help to see an example. It seems to me that you need a domain model separate from the EF class model, which is a data access layer to which not many DDD principles apply. The domain model should decide which of its changes are to be persisted, but once EF entity objects are changed they're either *all* saved or none.